# comparing common elements in bash that are unique

Tags: arrays, bash

i have two array like this:

```
a=(1 2 2 1)
b=(3 1 1 1)
```

i want to count common elements in them that are unique. for example the result of above is `1`.

**EDIT**
file:

```
 a=(1 2 2 1)
 b=(3 1 2 1)
 grep -f <(printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}") < <(printf "%s\n" "${b[@]}") | uniq
```

run: 
     ./test.sh

result:

```
  source test.sh 
    1
    2
    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep` and `sort -u`:

```
grep -f <(printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${b[@]}") | sort -u 
1
```

**Alternative awk command:**

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} $0 in a && !($0 in b){b[$0]} 
         END{for (i in b) print i}' <(printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${b[@]}")
1
```

Comment: Above grep outputs only single result `1` as shown, also see my awk command.

Comment: i have 3 result for `grep` command. why? a=(2 2 1 1) and b=(0 1 2 1)

Comment: Are you sure it is BASH that you're using? Did you try awk also?

Comment: See this **working demo: http://ideone.com/0n3ZpH** Just copy/paste from this code

Comment: grep basically mimics behavior of `grep -f "pattern-file" "search-file"` behavior here. Since arrays are not files therefore via process substitution `<(...)` it is passed to grep as it searches files.

Comment: Also if it worked out for you can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: In the second case where b is `(3 1 2 1)` the `grep` command supplied outputs `1 2 1`.

Comment: Yes that's correct, `sort -u` is better option. See updated answer.